# Rotating text using center in itext

Tags: rotation, itext

I'm converting a document which is created with a online editor. I need to be able to rotate the text using it's central point and not (0,0).

Since Image rotates using the centre I assumed this would work but it doesn't. Anyone has a clue how to rotate text using the central point in itext?

```
float fw = bf.getWidthPoint(text, textSize);
float fh = bf.getAscentPoint(text, textSize) - bf.getDescentPoint(text, textSize); 
PdfTemplate template = content.createTemplate(fw, fh);

Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0,fw, fw);
r.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.YELLOW);
template.rectangle(r);

template.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
template.beginText();
template.moveText(0, 0);
template.showText(text);
template.endText();

Image tmpImage = Image.getInstance(template);
tmpImage.setAbsolutePosition(Utilities.millimetersToPoints(x), Utilities.millimetersToPoints(pageHeight-(y+Utilities.pointsToMillimeters(fh))));
tmpImage.setRotationDegrees(0);
document.add(tmpImage);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you using `beginText()`, `moveText()`, `showText()`, `endText()`? Those methods are to be used by developers who speak PDF syntax fluently. Other developers should avoid using those low-level methods, because they are bound to make errors.

For instance: you're using the `setFontAndSize()` method outside a text object. That method is forbidden in graphics state, you can only use it in text state. Although Adobe Reader will probably tolerate it, Acrobat will complain when doing a syntax check.

Developers who don't speak PDF syntax fluently are advised to use convenience methods as demonstrated in the [TextMethods](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=246) example. Take a look at [text_methods.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter14/text_methods.pdf). The text "Away again Center" is probably what you need.

However, there's even an easier way to achieve what you want. Just use the static `showTextAligned()` method that is provided in the `ColumnText`class. That way you don't even need to use `beginText()`, `setFontAndSize()`, `endText()`:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(template,
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(text), x, y, rotation);
```

Using the `showTextAligned()` method in `ColumnText` also has the advantage that you can use a phrase that contains chunks with different fonts.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Paragraph in itext 7 :

```
    paragraph.setFixedPosition(....)
    paragraph.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(....));
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_POINT_X, textCenterX);
    paragraph.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_POINT_Y, textCenterY);
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is for itext 7. You might want to state that in your answer as the question and the other answer are for itext 5.