# How to place paragraphs in specific place using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, position, itext

How do I place text at a specific location on the pdf? I did a little bit of searching but didn't find anything too good. I have `document.Add(new Paragraph("Date:" + DateTime.Now));` and I wanted to place that on a specific area on the pdf file.

My code:

```
   private void savePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(nameTxtB.Text + "Repair.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        Document document = new Document();
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.LETTER);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        iTextSharp.text.Image r3tsLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("rt3slogo.PNG"); //creates r3ts logo
        iTextSharp.text.Image r3Info = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("R3 Information.PNG"); //creates r3 information text below r3ts logo

        r3tsLogo.SetAbsolutePosition(document.PageSize.Width - 375 - 0f, document.PageSize.Height - 130 - 0f); 
        r3Info.SetAbsolutePosition(document.PageSize.Width - 365 - 0f, document.PageSize.Height - 170 - 0f); //higher the number in height the lower the place of text on paper
                                   //less  number will result in text more to right in width

        //increase size of picture
        r3tsLogo.ScalePercent(120); 
        r3Info.ScalePercent(65);

//---------------adds all images to pdf file --------------------------------- 
        document.Add(r3tsLogo);
        document.Add(r3Info);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Date:" + DateTime.Now));




        document.Close(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to add images at an absolute position (see Joris' answer), but looking at how to add text, then the answer to your question is: use `ColumnText`.

If you only need to add a single line that doesn't need to be wrapped, you can use the `ShowTextAligned()` method:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
     Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("single line"), x, y, rotation);
```

In this line of code, `x` and `y` are the coordinates for the middle of the text (other possible alignment values are `ALIGN_LEFT` and `ALIGN_RIGHT`). The `rotation` parameter defines a rotation in degrees. Note that the text `"single line"` won't be wrapped. You can add text that "falls off the page" this way if the text you're adding is too long.

If you want to add text inside a specific rectangle, then you need to define the column using a `Rectangle` object:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(0, 0, 523, 50));
ct.addElement(new Paragraph("This could be a very long sentence that needs to be wrapped"));
ct.go();
```

If you provide more text than fits the rectangle, that text will not be rendered. However, it will still be available in the `ct` object so that you can add that remaining text at another position.

All of this has been asked and answered before:

**Single line:**

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370428/how-to-write-in-a-specific-location-the-zapfdingbatslist-in-a-pdf-document-using
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998306/rotating-text-using-center-in-itext

**Multiple lines:**

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609447
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152874/how-to-add-text-in-pdfcontentbyte-rectangle-using-itextsharp
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414923/rotate-paragraphs-or-cells-some-arbitrary-number-of-degrees-itext

Did I have to search long for these examples? No, I found them on the official web site under [Absolute Positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text).

Wisdom is there for those who search...

Comment: How to change Font in this one ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.DirectContent,
     Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("single line"), x, y, rotation);  ?

Answer (score 1):

This concept is thoroughly explained in the book 'iText in action'. Which can be found on the website.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3

Short code sample (check the site for other examples):

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document(PageSize.POSTCARD, 30, 30, 30, 30);

// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

// step 3
document.open();

// step 4
// Create and add a Paragraph
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Foobar Film Festival", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 22));
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(p);

// Create and add an Image
Image img = Image.getInstance(RESOURCE);
img.setAbsolutePosition(
        (PageSize.POSTCARD.getWidth() - img.getScaledWidth()) / 2,
        (PageSize.POSTCARD.getHeight() - img.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
document.add(img);
```

Comment: I think that the problem isn't positioning images, but positioning `"Date:" + DateTime.Now)` at an absolute position. Of course: this is also a question that has been answered many times before.